# Windows batch: How to remove last part of folders names

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file I get a folder with a list of subfolders with an unknown number of underscores e.g.:

```
a_b_10

c_d_e_2

f_17
```

I need to remove the last token of the names i.e.

```
a_b

c_d_e

f
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are all your directories on the same line in your question? It's not very easy to read.

Comment: where is the list of the folders ? in text file or the are in same directory?

Comment: I do dir /b /AD c:\MainFolder\ to get the list of folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out this solution:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /AD c:\MainFolder\') do (
    set var=%%f
    set var=!var:_= !
    set /a count=0
    for %%i in (!var!) do (set /a count+=1)
    set /a count2=0
    for %%i in (!var!) do (
        set /a count2+=1
        if /I !count2! equ 1 (set var2=%%i) else if not !count2! equ !count! (set var2=!var2!_%%i)
    )
    echo !var2!
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to get the last part with an underscore and then remove this from your string, but this only works when the last part is unique.

In your sample the last part seems to be always a number in spite of the other parts.
This uses the trick to parse parts of a string by replace the delimiter by a linefeed character.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


for /F "delims=" %%X in ('dir /b /AD') do (
    call :removeLastPart "%%~X"
)
exit /b

:removeLastPart
set "str=%~1"
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (
  for /F "delims=" %%P in ("!str:_=%%~L!") do set "last=%%P"
)
echo The last part is '!last!'

REM ** now remove the last part by replacing with nothing **
set "str=!str:_%last%=!"
echo !str!
exit /b
```

Comment: thanks jeb. about the same length as my solution below just mine w/o goto's.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set "root_dir=C:\scriptests"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%d in ('dir /b /a:d *_*') do (
     call :lastindexof "%%d" _ lio
     set "f_name=%%~d"
     echo renaming  !f_name! 
     for %%S in (!lio!) do ren !f_name! !f_name:~0,%%S!

)
endlocal



exit /b 0
:lastindexof [%1 - string ; %2 - find last index of ; %3 - if defined will store the result in variable with same name]
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion 


set "str=%~1"
set "splitter=%~2"

set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines are required
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%L in ("!LF!") DO (
    for /f "delims=" %%R in ("!splitter!") do ( 
        set "var=!str:%%R=%%L!"
    )
)

for /f  delims^=^" %%P in ("!var!") DO ( 
    set "last_part=%%~P"  
)



if "!last_part!" equ ""  if "%~3" NEQ "" (
 echo "not contained" >2 
 endlocal
 set %~3=-1 
 exit
) else (
 echo "not contained" >2 
 endlocal
 echo -1 
)


call :strlen0.3 str strlen 
call :strlen0.3 last_part plen 
call :strlen0.3 splitter slen 

set /a lio=strlen-plen-slen
endlocal & set lio=%lio%
endlocal & if "%~3" NEQ "" (set %~3=%lio%) else echo %lio%
exit /b 0

:strlen0.3  StrVar  [RtnVar]
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "s=#!%~1!"
  set "len=0"
  for %%A in (2187 729 243 81 27 9 3 1) do (
    set /A mod=2*%%A
    for %%Z in (!mod!) do (
        if "!s:~%%Z,1!" neq "" (
            set /a "len+=%%Z"
            set "s=!s:~%%Z!"

        ) else (
            if "!s:~%%A,1!" neq "" (
                set /a "len+=%%A"
                set "s=!s:~%%A!"
            )
        )
    )
  )
  endlocal & if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo **%len%**
exit /b
```

Comment: Also nice, a bit long, but I can't find the explanation

Comment: @jeb - The idea is almost the same as your. It uses two subroutines one for string length and one standard lastindexof. May be I should more comments in the code.

Answer (score 2):

This solution will create the `"renfolders.bat.txt"` file for you to check in notepad, and run it as a batch file if you are happy with it.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
dir *_* /b /s /ad |repl ".*\\(.*)_.*" "ren \q$&\q \q$1\q" xa >"renfolders.bat.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a novel approach

For each folder containing at least one `_` in name:

- create a temporary empty file with the same name
- rename the temporary file, stripping off everything after the final `_`
- read the new name into a variable
- strip off the final `_` from the name

For an explanation of how the rename works, see [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "loc=%temp%\removeToken"
md "%loc%"
for /d %%F in (*_*) do (
  copy nul "%loc%\%%F" >nul
  ren "%loc%\*" "*_"
  for %%A in ("%loc%\*") do set "new=%%~nxA"
  del /q "%loc%\*"
  echo old=%%F
  echo new=!new:~0,-1!
  echo(
)
rd "%loc%"
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED - Wrong copy of the code posted

It separates the elements of the directory name and iterates over them discarting the last element

```
@echo off

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%a in (*_*) do (
        set "old=%%~na" & set "new=" & set "previous="
        for %%b in ("!old:_=" "!") do (
            if not defined previous ( 
                set "previous=%%~b" 
            ) else if not defined new (
                set "new=!previous!"
            ) else set "new=!new!_!previous!" 
            set "previous=%%~b" 
        )
        echo ren "%%~fa" "!new!"
    )

    endlocal
```